# Produce where clause for 5 months ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm haveing trouble with this case expression on this line

```
DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate()))
```

If I delete this line it works fine but if I leave it out it selects records from every Decemeber and not just from December 2012 like I want.

I've searched everywhere and I can't figure it out.

```
Select C.CustId ,
Sum(Case DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate)
When DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate())) and
     DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate()))
  Then Ia.Amount 
  Else 0 End) As 'Total0'
from Invoice I 
inner join InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  on I.GUIDInvoice=Ia.GUIDInvoice
inner join Customer C on  C.GUIDCustomer=I.GUIDCustomer
group by C.CustId
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you ran this query on? Why do you tagged your question with MySQL, SQL Server and sqlite?

Comment: There are about 12 years a millenia where this could produce results.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate())) = 12 and ... = 2012 ??? When is a condition as in X = Y And Z = Y, you have X and Z..

Comment: I want to just return records from 5 months ago with out having to declare the year like this select ... FROM ... where YEAR(getdate()) = 2012 AND MONTH(getdate()) = 12

Comment: Ooops, I mean 12 years an epoch, 24 altogether is you include AD and BC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want

```
SELECT
            C.CustId,
            SUM
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN
      DATEPART(mm, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate()))
  AND
      DATEPART(yyyy, I.InvoiceDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate()))
                        THEN Ia.Amount
                    ELSE
                        0
                END
            ) [Total0]
    FROM 
            Invoice I 
        JOIN
            InvoiceAmtSummary Ia  
                ON I.GUIDInvoice = Ia.GUIDInvoice
        JOIN
            Customer C 
                ON  C.GUIDCustomer = I.GUIDCustomer
    GROUP BY
            C.CustId
```

---

Or, more sensibly

```
DECLARE @TargetDate DateTime;
DECLARE @TargetYear Int;
DECLARE @TargetMonth Month;

SET @TagetDate = DATEADD(mm, -5, getdate()));
SET @TargetYear = YEAR(@TargetDate);
SET @TargetMonth = MONTH(@TargetDate);

SELECT
            C.CustId,
            SUM(COALESCE(Ia.Amount, 0))
     FROM
            Customer C
         LEFT JOIN
            ( 
            SELECT
                         MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) Month,
                         YEAR(I.InvoiceYear) Year,
                         I.GUIDInvoice,
                         I.GUIDCustomer
                FROM
                         Invoice I
            ) S
                ON S.GUIDCustomer = C.GUIDCustomer
         LEFT JOIN
            InvoiceAmtSummary Ia
                ON Ia.GUIDInvoice = S.GUIDInvoice
     WHERE
             S.Year = @TargetYear
         AND
             S.Month = @TargetMonth
     GROUP BY
             C.CustID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh, why not:

```
WHERE InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-4, 0)
  AND InvoiceDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-3, 0)
```

This ends up evaluating (today, April 5, 2013) as:

```
WHERE InvoiceDate >= '2012-12-01'
  AND InvoiceDate <  '2013-01-01'
```

Put into your query:

```
SELECT C.CustId,
  [Total0] = SUM(CASE 
    WHEN InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-4, 0)
     AND InvoiceDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-3, 0)
    THEN Ia.Amount ELSE 0 END
  )
FROM dbo.Invoice AS I 
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceAmtSummary AS Ia 
   ON I.GUIDInvoice = Ia.GUIDInvoice
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS C 
   ON C.GUIDCustomer = I.GUIDCustomer
GROUP BY C.CustId;
```

Although you might want to put that in the `WHERE` clause, unless you want to include customers who didn't have a sale that month (seems like it would be logical to leave them out, since you're already leaving out customers who have never had an invoice). e.g.

```
SELECT C.CustId, Total0 = SUM(Ia.Amount)
FROM dbo.Invoice AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceAmtSummary AS Ia 
   ON I.GUIDInvoice = Ia.GUIDInvoice
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS C 
   ON C.GUIDCustomer = I.GUIDCustomer
   WHERE InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-4, 0)
     AND InvoiceDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-3, 0)
GROUP BY C.CustId;
```

Anyway, now you actually have a shot at using an index on `InvoiceDate` instead of this `DATEPART(MONTH` hack that is non-sargable.

Also a few other tips:

1. Spell out what you mean. Why type `yyyy` when you could type `YEAR` and be more explicit? To see why this is important, try to guess what this will return, and then try to figure out why it doesn't do what you think:

   ```
   SELECT DATEPART(y, GETDATE());
   ```
2. Your syntax wasn't correct. You can't say `CASE WHEN (some boolean expression) THEN` - you must compare it to something. `CASE` isn't a boolean construct, it's an expression that returns a single result. So you must evaulate it, something like `CASE WHEN (expression) = 1 THEN`...
3. Please don't use `AS 'alias'` syntax with single quotes. [When delimiters are necessary (they're not in this case), use `[square brackets]`](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). Certain forms of single quote delimiters for aliases are deprecated, and they make code harder to read because they look like string literals.
4. Please read the following articles on date range queries:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

To select only records of December 2012 try

```
select ... FROM ... where YEAR(your_timestamp) = 2012 AND MONTH(your_timestamp) = 12
```

Comment: I need it to be dynamic so that when we are at april 2014 it returns records from dec 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It gives you dynamic all records for the month now - 5

```
select ... FROM ... where YEAR(your_timestamp) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) AND MONTH(your_timestamp) = Month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH))
```